# The name 'Source' wasn't recognized. VBA for a PowerQuery

Tags: vba

I've created a macro that is transforming data for a PowerQuery. However despite recording the macro as I manually created it, now when I run it through as a macro I get an error "The name 'Source' wasnt recognized".

After playing around with the code in different areas I'm still unable to get it run as required:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table1", Formula:= _
    "let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""Table1""]}[Content]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "   #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""C" & _
    "olumn10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type text}, {""Column17"", type text}, {""Column18"", type text}, {""Column19"", type text}, {""Column20"", type text}, {""Column21"", type text}, {""Column22"", type text}, {""Column23"", type t" & _
    "ext}}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Changed Type"",""Company Limited by Guarantee with Share Capital"",""11"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value1"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value"",""Company Limited by Share Capital"",""1"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value2"" = Table.ReplaceVal" & _
    "ue(#""Replaced Value1"",""European Public Limited Liability Company (SE)"",""48"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value3"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value2"",""Incorporated - Industrial & Provident Society Act"",""6"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value4"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value3"",""Incorpor" & _
    "ated under Building Societies Act 1986"",""44"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value5"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value4"",""Incorporated under Friendly Society Act 1992"",""45"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value6"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value5"",""Limited Liability Partnership"",""42"",Replace" & _
    "r.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value7"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value6"",""Company Limited by Guarantee with No Share Capital"",""12"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value8"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value7"",""Limited Partnership"",""24"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value9"" " & _
    "= Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value8"",""Municipality or State e.g New South Wales"",""34"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value10"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value9"",""Not Migrated"",""7"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value11"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value10"",""Not Supplied"",""8"",Replacer" & _
    ".ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value12"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value11"",""Not Yet Formed"",""29"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value13"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value12"",""Registered - Other Company Type by Companies House"",""49"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value14"" =" & _
    " Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value13"",""Overseas Firm Incorporated"",""50"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value15"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value14"",""Overseas Firm Unincorporated"",""51"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value16"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value15"",""PLC"",""4"",Replacer.Repla" & _
    "ceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value17"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value16"",""Partnership"",""23"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value18"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value17"",""Private Unlimited Company"",""30"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value19"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Va" & _
    "lue18"",""Other"",""99"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value20"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value19"",""Registered as Overseas Company by Companies House"",""47"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value21"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value20"",""Registered as a Northern Ireland credit union"",""52"",Repla" & _
    "cer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value22"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value21"",""Registered under Friendly Society Act 1974"",""46"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value23"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value22"",""Registered under I&PS Act 1965 and CU Act 1979"",""43"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & _
    "    #""Replaced Value24"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value23"",""Sole Trader"",""3"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value25"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value24"",""Trust"",""22"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value26"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value25"",""UK Co incorporated by Special Act/Roya" & _
    "l Charter"",""2"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value27"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value26"",""UK body created by Special Act/Royal Charter"",""14"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value28"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value27"",""Unincorporated Body"",""21"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "  " & _
    "  #""Replaced Value29"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value28"",""Limited"",""5"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column3""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value30"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value29"",""Appointed Representative"",""6"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value31"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value30"",""Branch (UK) of a Overseas " & _
    "Firm"",""2"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value32"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value31"",""CBTL"",""34"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value33"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value32"",""Claims Management"",""37"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value34"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#" & _
    """Replaced Value33"",""Trustee/Depositary"",""12"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value35"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value34"",""Introducer A.R."",""27"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value36"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value35"",""Operator"",""11"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Re" & _
    "placed Value37"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value36"",""Regulated"",""1"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value38"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value37"",""Services (UK) of an Overseas Firm"",""5"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value39"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value38"",""Trustee"",""9"",Replac" & _
    "er.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value40"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value39"",""Depositary"",""10"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value41"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value40"",""UK Representative"",""13"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value42"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Val" & _
    "ue41"",""Credit Rating Agency"",""99"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value43"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value42"",""Data Reporting Service Provider"",""98"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value44"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value43"",""Trade Repository"",""97"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column4""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & _
    "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value45"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value44"",""Not hold and not control client money"",""N"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column5""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value46"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value45"",""Hold and control client money"",""Y"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column5""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value47"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replace" & _
    "d Value46"",""Control but not hold client money"",""N"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column5""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value48"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Replaced Value47"","""",""X"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{""Column5""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Split Column by Delimiter"" = Table.SplitColumn(#""Replaced Value48"", ""Column12"", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("" "", QuoteStyle.Csv), {""" & _
    "Column12.1"", ""Column12.2""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type1"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Split Column by Delimiter"",{{""Column12.1"", type text}, {""Column12.2"", type text}}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value49"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Changed Type1"",""+44Â"",""+44"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Column13""}), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Split Column by Position"" = Table.SplitColumn(#""Re" & _
    ""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Table1;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table1_2"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Any tips / pointers or advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The string containing the code is unreadable as is. Dump the generated content into a file and check it

Comment: Which string is unreadable? What content as nothing is being output due to the source error

Comment: The one that contains the first formula you're trying to add

Comment: I've checked through the formula and cant see anything untoward, as mentioned in my post this part of the macro has been copied from the recording so all should be as expected?